# OLSreg: replacement has more rows than the data

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple OLS regression with R but it says that:

```
> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(119L, 234L, 185L, 99L,  : 
  replacement has 510 rows, data has 102
```

Here is my short code:

```
Y <- cbind(dem)
X <- cbind(income, hs, ba, density, region)

olsreg <- lm(Y ~ X)
```

My data has 102 observations.

I do to know what to do and I would be very grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: This is not an rstudio related question. It's about R

Comment: do `X` and `Y` have the same number of rows?

Comment: What makes you think this syntax will work? `X <- iris[, 2:5]; Y <- iris[, 1, drop = FALSE];lm(Y ~ X)`. Make your data into a proper data.frame `lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)`.